# Oracle Temp Table Space - Alias clean up ORA-01119

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

How to drop the temp table space including alias.

```
SQL> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMPRM_TEMP;
SQL> ALTER  TABLESPACE TEMPRM_TEMP ADD TEMPFILE '+TEMPDATA/rm/datafile/TEMPRM_TEMPFILE_1.dbf' SIZE 2M;
SQL> DROP TABLESPACE TEMPRM_TEMP INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;     
SQL> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMPRM_TEMP;       
SQL> ALTER  TABLESPACE TEMPRM_TEMP ADD TEMPFILE '+TEMPDATA/rm/datafile/TEMPRM_TEMPFILE_1.dbf' SIZE 2M
         *
         ERROR at line 1:
         ORA-01119: error in creating database file
         '+TEMPDATA/rm/datafile/TEMPRM_TEMPFILE_1.dbf'
         ORA-17502: ksfdcre:4 Failed to create file
         +TEMPDATA/rm/datafile/TEMPRM_TEMPFILE_1.dbf
         ORA-15005: name "rm/datafile/TEMPRM_TEMPFILE_1.dbf" is already used by an
         existing alias
```

Please explain, how to clean Alias in Oracle ASM  ?
thanks

Comment: The error seems relatively self-explanatory. Does that DBF exist?

Comment: Yes.. my question is why 'DROP TABLESPACE' is not able clean the alias ?

Comment: You can see you're using two file names, right? Some other temporary TS is using, or has used, `TEMPRM_TEMPFILE_1.dbf`. Maybe you tried to create it before with a different TS name? What does [`dba_temp_files`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_5061.htm) show? Or you created and dropped it with that name previously, but without `including datafiles`?

Comment: Your edit is making things even less clear - what did you really run? What temporary file name was allocated by the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMPRM_TEMP` statement?

Comment: Steps as below. 1)Create TS 2)Add file TS 3)DROP TS 4) Create TS with same name as in step 1 2)Add file with same name in step 2

Comment: Ok I have resolved it ASMCMD> rmalias '+TEMPDATA/rm/datafile/TEMPRM_TEMPFILE_1.dbf'.. By removing the alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by removing Alias

```
ASMCMD> rmalias '+TEMPDATA/rm/datafile/TEMPRM_TEMPFILE_1.dbf'
```